# How to bulk load into cassandra other than copy method.?

Tags: csv, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

AM using the copy method for cpying the .csv file into the cassandra tables..
But am getting records mismatch error..

```
Record 41(Line 41) has mismatched number of records (85 instead of 82)
```

This is happening for all the .csv files & all the .csv files are system generated..

Any work around for this error..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error message, it sounds like the copy command is working for you, until record 41.  What are you using as a delimiter?  The default delimiter for the `COPY` command is a comma, and I'll bet that your data has some additional commas in it on line 41.

A few options:

- Edit your data and remove the extra commas.
- Alter your .csv file to encapsulate the values of all of your fields in double-quotes, as `COPY`'s default `QUOTE` value is <kbd>"</kbd>.  This will allow you to leave the in-text commas.
- Alter your .csv file to delimit with pipes <kbd>|</kbd> instead of a comma, and set the `COPY` command's `DELIMITER` option to <kbd>|</kbd>.
- Try using either the [Cassandra bulk loader](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html) or [json2sstable utility](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsJson2sstable_t.html) to import your data.  I've never used them, but I would bet you'll have similar problems if you have commas in your data set.

Comment: hey Bryce, I got another problem now.. One of my record has pipe in it, and again at that line the same error pops up.. "records mismatch error" I think its the pipe in the record that is being treated as a delimiter. I am trying other delimiters like pound & euro symbols but they dont just work as they are not Single-Character delimiters. Can u can suggest me new delimiter or is there any way to load .tsv files into cassandra.?

Comment: If you can't get around the problem of field values containing your delimiter, then try my 2nd option (encapsulating all field values in quotes) specifying `QUOTE` as " or '.  Otherwise, you can try escaping pipes in field values with a backslash.